# How do you find an item in a repository by something other than id

Tags: loopbackjs, strongloop

If I have a repository with many properties and I want to find something by the non-id property, do I just find all and then return the data after a boolean comparison, or is there a better way to find by a property that's not the ID?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In loopback4, you need to use repository for this purpose. Do as below.

For case where you know there will be just one entry with value. (Unique columns)

```
const user = await this.userRepository.findOne({
  where: {
    username: 'test_admin'
  }
});
```

For case where there can be multiple.

```
const user = await this.userRepository.find({
  where: {
    firstName: 'test admin'
  }
});
```

Comment: If this resolves your query, I'll be glad if you can accept this as answer.

Comment: Is it possible to do comparisons for where? Like where count (column) > 1?

Comment: Yes possible. where: {
        count: {
          gt: 1
        }
      }

Comment: Check this out - https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Where-filter.html#operators

Answer (score 1):

For Loopback 3, here you find the documentation for querying data: https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Querying-data.html

Basically, use a query filter like this:

```js
const objects = await app.models.ModelName.find(
  {
    where: {
      propertyName: value
    }
  }
)
```

Don't forget to define an index for the property you want to query because otherwise, the database engine will perform a full table scan.

```js
"properties": {
  "propertyName": {
    "type": "string",
    "index": {
      "unique": true
    }
  },
  ...
}
```

Comment: What about for loopback 4?

Comment: never used, please specify Loopback 4 in the question title